# Adobe DPS Webview caching problems

Tags: ios, caching, webview, adobe-dps

Hi we've been working with Adobe DPS for a while now and we just started using html to support some more advanced interactions. So we inserted the html & assets locally into a webview.

When updating these files the webview doesn't update. It looks like the webview is caching everything(html/css/js/images) extremely hard.

Is there any way to prevent these webviews from caching just for development purposes?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`location.reload(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload) in your javascript to trigger a hard refresh. the first argument specifies that the reload should be a "hard refresh"

Obviously you can't call it on page load or you'll end up with an infinite loop of reloads, but you could add a development-only button in the page along the lines of:

```
<button onclick="location.reload(true);">hard refresh</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try adding the following Meta tags in your HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```